# Comparing counts between groups with replicates

Tags: chi-squared-test, count-data, contingency-tables

I hope you can help me.
I need to compare count data (number of grazed plants among plants previously marked inside a plot) recorded in 4 different sites (replicates), each of them receiving 2 different treatments (different grazing practices). Treatments were the same in all 4 sites as well as the number of marked plants was the same across sites and treatments. Below an example of the dataset and of the resulting table.
I'm interested to see if the number of grazed plants differs between treatments (grazing practice). I'm not interested in the difference among the 4 replicates (sites) but somehow I have to take them into account in the analysis.
I was thinking to use the Chi-Square Test for Homogeneity of Proportions (which should be like a 2x2 contingency table, right?), but I'm not sure it is appropriate since "site" is a replicate and not a factor.
Any advice? Thanks!!!
P.S. I've been using SPSS, not R!

[image]

Comment: Design is not clear. Can you give a table with real (or slightly fake) data showing the connections among treatments, sites, and farms? There are lots of ways to count number of plants: Is it number of plants growing from a known number of seeds? the number of plants surviving among a known number at the start? Or something else?

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for asking. I added some notes in my original post. I hope that can help!